# Maximum length of request for Restful spring based MVC

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, restful-architecture

i wanted to know if there will be any limit of maximum length of request data for Spring MVC based restful web services i.e. Is there any limit which says single request should not contain more then certain number of character ?

```
class Example {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("This is a simple Java program.");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to 3.2.1 General Syntax, [Hypertext Transfer Protocol/1.1](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt):

> Note: Servers ought to be cautious about depending on URI lengths above **255 bytes**, because some older client or proxy implementations might not properly support these lengths.

Personally I always keep my HTTP GET requests length below 256 just to be safe, althought it's not practical nowadays. I think **2048-** is acceptable these days.